# Sort gridview columns ascending and descending

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to program my page in vb.net and asp.net so that when a user clicks on a column heading of a gridview, the data is sorted either in ascending or descending order.

Please note that my data is coming from an SQL Server Express database.

So far, I have done it so that the gridview can be sorted:

```xml
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Height="143px" AllowSorting="true" />
```

I get a message saying:

The GridView 'GridView1' fired event Sorting which wasn't handled.

I dont quite understand what this means.

Can anybody advise please on what this means and what I need to do to overcome this?

Many thanks in advance.

Dan

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide Sorting event handler in your Grid declaration

```xml
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Height="143px" 
AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="OnSortingHandler" />
```

And then provide `OnSortingHandler` method implementation in code behind

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the DataSource of your GridView programmatically, set its DataSourceID property instead of DataSource then you'll be able to use the default sorting function.